# C# issue using "Or"

Tags: c#

I am trying to say here if `userinput = 1` or `2` display the message `"you won a new car"`, but it is not working.

The error says

> "operator || cannot be applied to operands of type and string".

I have been doing C# for only 2 days.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" 1 2 or 3");
            String message = Console.ReadLine();
            string userinput = "";
            if (userinput == "1" || "2")
                message = "you won a new car";
```

Comment: Sorry I am trying to reformat this so you can read it not

Comment: This one is pretty easy to google though "C# if statement or". You'll safe a lot of time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Doesn't work like that I'm afraid! Use:

```
if(userinput == "1" || userinput == "2")
```

The reason for this is that the if statement is expecting a true or false result. With a boolean operator (||), both sides must evaluate to either true or false. In this case, userinput == "1" will evaluate to true if userinput is 1, otherwise it will be false. The standalone "2" doesn't evaluate to true or false, it evaluates to "2".

Answer (score 2):

Your last line needs to be changed to:

```
if (userinput == "1" || userinput == "2") 
    message = "you won a new car";
```

Each part of the statement separated by the "OR" operator needs to be able to evaluate to true or false.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
if(userinput == "1" || userinput == "2")
```

The trick is that or says one binary condition **OR** the other must be true for true. It is boolean logic, not the english or for lists.

Answer (score 1):

Subsequently you could do something like this:

```
message = userinput != 3 ? "you won a new car" : "you lost a new car"
```

Which is a conditional operator expression.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **[Array.IndexOf](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-indexof)** if you have multiple values.

ex. if you have 10 values that you want to compare by using `OR`,you can just use `Array.IndexOf` to shorten the code..

```
string[] array= new string[2];
array[0] = "1";
array[1] = "2";

if( Array.IndexOf(array, userInput) != -1) //-1 means it doesn't exist
{
   message = "you won a new car";
}
```